# Inner shadow effect for QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to add an inner shadow effect to some of my widgets:
[image: comparison]
I've found the [QGraphicsDropShadowEffect Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html), but it doesn't seem to exist for inner shadow.
I've seen [InnerShadow QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-innershadow.html) too, but I'm not using QML.

Is it actually possible to do without using QML? Maybe using stylesheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Stylesheet

Unfortunately, in the meanwhile [Qt style sheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#border) doesn't support something like "box-shadow" in css. One way to workaround is to use a top and left gradient border to mimic the effect.

```
border-left: 20px solid black;
border-top: 20px solid black;
border-left-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop: 0 rgb(195,195,195), stop: 1 rgb(240, 240, 240));
border-top-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop: 0 rgb(195,195,195), stop: 1 rgb(240, 240, 240));
background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
```

Here is a example using python, however, the stylesheet part is the same for C++ user.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QGridLayout


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.resize(600, 400)
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setObjectName("w1")
        self.widget2 = QWidget()
        self.widget2.setObjectName("w2")
        self.widget3 = QWidget()
        self.widget3.setObjectName("w3")

        self.label = QLabel("20px")
        self.label2 = QLabel("10px")
        self.label3 = QLabel("3px")

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.label2, 0, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.label3, 0, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget, 1, 0, 3, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget2, 1, 1, 3, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget3, 1, 2, 3, 1)
        layout.setHorizontalSpacing(20)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setStyleSheet("""
                        QWidget{ background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}
                        QLabel {font-size: 20px}
                        QWidget#w1 {
                            border-left: 20px solid black;
                            border-top: 20px solid black;
                            border-left-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop: 0 rgb(195,195,195), stop: 1 rgb(240, 240, 240));
                            border-top-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop: 0 rgb(195,195,195), stop: 1 rgb(240, 240, 240));
                            background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
                            }
                        QWidget#w2 {
                            border-left: 10px solid black;
                            border-top: 10px solid black;
                            border-left-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop: 0 rgb(195,195,195), stop: 1 rgb(240, 240, 240));
                            border-top-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop: 0 rgb(195,195,195), stop: 1 rgb(240, 240, 240));
                            background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
                            }
                        QWidget#w3 {
                            border-left: 3px solid black;
                            border-top: 3px solid black;
                            border-left-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop: 0 rgb(195,195,195), stop: 1 rgb(240, 240, 240));
                            border-top-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop: 0 rgb(195,195,195), stop: 1 rgb(240, 240, 240));
                            background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
                            }
                        
                        
                        """)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

### 2. QFrame

Another way to create a inner shadow is to set [QFrame style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html).

Something like this:

```cpp
QLabel label(...);
label.setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Sunken);
label.setLineWidth(2);
label.setMidLineWidth(1);
```

Here are some combinations of styles and line widths listed in the document.

[image]